# Get remote of current branch

Tags: git, alias

How can I easily get a remote of current branch? I want to create an alias for pushing current branch to it's upstream, so I'd like something like:

```
bpush = push {current remote} HEAD
```

How can I reliably get the second argument though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First configure your local git repo to only push current branch to its upstream branch instead of all matching branches:

`git config push.default tracking`

Then a simple

`git push`

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a remote branch as the upstream of the local one, you already have a "shortcut".

```
git push
```

Comment: Actually `git push` pushes all matching branches to the remote of current branch. I'd like to limit it to the current branch only.